# Storing a Closure Function in a Class Property in PHP

Tags: php, class, function, methods, closures

ok I do have the code below

```
<?php
    class foo{
       public $bar = NULL;

       public function boo(){
          $this->bar();
       }
    }

    $mee = new foo();

    //save a closure function on the property
    $mee->bar = function(){
        echo 'hahaha';
    };

    //invoke the closure function by using a class method
    $mee->boo();
?>
```

and you can see it running here http://codepad.org/s1jhi7cv

now what i want here is to store the closure function on the class method.

well closures are possible as i read the documentation about it here http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

is this possible? did i went to something wrong? please correct me

Comment: You shouldn't use "codepad.org" for this, they are using a pretty old version of PHP that does not yet support closures.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your example code at codepad.org does not work because codepad.org uses PHP 5.2.5, and closure support was only added in 5.3.

However, your code will also not work in a PHP version that supports closures, although you will get a different error: http://codepad.viper-7.com/Ob0bH5

This is a limitation of PHP at present. `$obj->member()` looks for a method named `member` and will not look at properties to see if they are callable. It is, frankly, annoying.

The only way I am aware of to make this work without `call_user_func()`/`call_user_func_array()` is:

```
public function boo() {
   $func = $this->bar;
   $func();
}
```

Comment: @Mahan It won't work on codepad.org (see edit above), you need at least 5.3. Works [here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/dB3ckH)

Answer (score 4):

You need to exploit some magic functionality of PHP (`__call`) to make use of that. Extend from `Extendable` for example:

```
class Extendable {
    static function import($context) {
        $self = new static();
        while (is_callable($context)) $context = $context($self);
        if (is_array($context) || is_object($context) || is_a($context, 'Traversable')) {
            foreach($context as $key => $value)
                $self->$key = &$value; # preserve keys if
        }
        return $self;
    }
    public function __call($name, $args) {
        if (isset($this->$name) && is_callable($this->$name)) {
            return call_user_func_array($this->$name, $args);
        }
        throw new BadFunctionCallException(sprintf('Undefined function %s.', $name));
    }
}
```

And you can do the job. It's not that nice. Background and examples are in one of my blog posts:

- [PHP: Extending stdClass with Closures (plus Visitor)](http://hakre.wordpress.com/2011/03/30/php-extending-stdclass-with-closures-plus-visitor/)

You can naturally implement that magic functionality your own, too.

Comment: Nice, could easily be turned into a trait as well if you want to extend some other base class with this functionality.

Comment: Yeah, true. However I do not know if using traits for magic function is not calling for trouble in the first place ;)

Comment: +1.  I would throw [`BadMethodCallException`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.badmethodcallexception.php) instead, though.

Comment: Yeh I thought exactly that after I wrote the comment. Although I little of the danger is taken out because a trait method can still be overridden, but that breaks the whole purpose of the trait. Meh.

Comment: @drrcknlsn: Or maybe an [`UnexpectedValueException`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.unexpectedvalueexception.php). These exception names are a mess in PHP :I)

Answer (score 4):

Use `call_user_func()` function:

```
<?php
    class foo{
       public $bar = NULL;

       public function boo(){
          call_user_func($this->bar);
       }
    }

    $mee = new foo();

    //save a closure function on the property
    $mee->bar = function(){
        echo 'hahaha';
    };

    //invoke the closure function by using a class method
    $mee->boo();
```

This will display "ahahah"

Hope it helps.

Comment: Actually it will display "hahaha" :D

Answer (score 3):

**New syntax as of PHP 7:**

You can put round brackets around the instance and method to call the method like so: `($this->bar)();`.

This causes a syntax error on earlier versions.

If anyone has a reference to the documentation for this change, please comment it.

Answer (score 2):

You will not be able to do that.

Take for example this code:

```
class T {
  function foo() {
    echo 'T::foo';
  }
}

$t = new T;
$t->foo = function() {
  echo 'Closure::foo';
};
$t->foo();
```

It works fine on PHP 5.4.6 and/or PHP 5.3.16, however it will result in `T::foo` getting printed.

This happens because methods, in PHP, are not modifiable class properties, as they are for example in javascript.

However,

```
$foo = $t->foo;
$foo();
```

will print `Closure::foo` as expected.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is not a prototype based language hence you cannot redefine functions

Answer (score 0):

Use `__call` to catch all non-defined methods and then look up the closure and invoke it. Take a look at my post on this [SitePoint thread](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?565576-Javascript-style-PHP-with-PHP-5-3-0).

Comment: can you give an example code please? sorry i don't have experience using __call thank you

Comment: An exemplary `__call` function you can find in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12196625/367456) as well.

Comment: External link is dead.