# Passing variable defined as a function, through as a paramter, and calling it in that function - PHP

Tags: php, delegates

I have the following:

```
class Delegator
{
    public $Create;
    public $Update;
    public $Delete;
}

// Inside controller 1

$delegator = new Delegator();
$delegator->Create = function(){ /**/ };
$delegator->Update = function(){ /**/ };
$delegator->Delete = function(){ /**/ };

InvokeAction( $delegator );

//-------------------

// Inside controller 2

function InvokeAction( Delegator &$delegator )
{
    switch( $something )
    {
        case "create":
            $delegator->Create(); // Says Create method is undefined.
        break;
    }
}

//-------------------
```

In the Invoke action function, it calls the Create variable as if it's a function, but it cannot see it? any ideas what i'm doing wrong?

**ANSWER----------------**

```
call_user_func( $delegator->Create, /* parameters go here if needs be */ );
```

Comment: `$something` is never defined, so the `switch` expression will always be `null`.

Comment: What do you mean by `it cannot see it`?

Comment: Says Create method is undefined.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Storing a Closure Function in a Class Property in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12196408/storing-a-closure-function-in-a-class-property-in-php)

Comment: THANKYOUUUUU THAT WORKED FOR ME!!! LOVE YOU LOADS...

Comment: To all, do not dare close this question, it is extremely helpful!

Comment: I'd say my pleasure, but I'm afraid you'd get too excited...