# Binding a closure to a class as a new method

Tags: php, closures

I am building an API class that extends the functionality of a vendor class. The vendor class expects to be extended, and will check for the existence of methods like this:

```
if (method_exists($this, 'block'.$CurrentBlock['type']))
{
    $CurrentBlock = $this->{'block'.$CurrentBlock['type']}($CurrentBlock);
}
```

So since my API is also a vendor file, I thought I'd do something clever and try to let people pass closures into my API and have that extend the class.

```
public function extendBlock($blockName, Closure $closure)
{
    $methodName = camel_case("block_{$blockName}");
    $this->{$methodName} = $closure;

    return method_exists($this, $methodName);
}
```

This would theoretically bind the closure so that the call in my first codeblock would succeed... but that doesn't happen. It is not seen as a method, but rather a property which contains a closure. Not only does `method_exist` fail, but attempting to call the method fails.

Here's a modified version where I'm trying to figure out what's going wrong.

```
public function extendBlock($blockName, Closure $closure)
{
    $methodName = camel_case("block_{$blockName}");
    $newClosure = clone $closure;
    $newClosure = $newClosure->bindTo($this);

    $this->{$methodName} = $newClosure;
    $this->{$methodName}();

    return method_exists($this, $methodName);
}
```

None of this works. The property is definitely set and the scope for `$this` in `$closure` is currently pointing to the `$this` of that method.

If I run this instead, the closure executes correctly.

```
    $this->{$methodName} = $newClosure;
    //$this->{$methodName}();

    $foobar = $this->{$methodName};
    $foobar();
```

So yeah. I was really hoping for a nice, tidy way of satisfying the check in my first codeblock without requiring the user to inherit my class and write them directly, but I don't think that's possible.

Edit: This is slightly different from [Storing a Closure Function in a Class Property in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12196408/storing-a-closure-function-in-a-class-property-in-php) -- while the solution with `__call` that was provided there is *excellent* and is worth looking into if you're curious about binding closures to a class, this method *does not* trick the `method_exists` check.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Storing a Closure Function in a Class Property in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12196408/storing-a-closure-function-in-a-class-property-in-php). See [this answer particularly](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12196625/1446005). I would reconsider this approach, inheritance is *the* right way to do what you want. Alternatively, check out [traits](http://php.net/manual/fr/language.oop5.traits.php).

Comment: @RandomSeed Traits can't be bound after compilation, and while that question you provided is very interesting and an excellent solution, the constraints of my question means I have to also trick `method_exists`, which setting `__call` does not do.

Comment: Do you really need `method_exists()` to return `true` ? In the other answer, `is_callable()` did the job.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, it does. Without touching the library I can't get around it. I would say the question you linked to would answer 99% of the people asking the same thing, though. I don't think I have any choice but to deal with project owner.

Comment: Ok, I see that you are already aware this is an ugly hack. Please slap the project owner for me :) PS: `clone` seems to be superfluous as `Closure::bindTo()` already "**Duplicates** the closure with a new bound object and class scope"

Answer (score 2):

It will not work with [`method_exists()`](http://php.net/method_exists) as that function provides information based on methods which are declared explicitly in the class scope. However, there is still workaround with magic methods. [`__call()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call) to be precise:

```
class Caller
{
    public function bind($method, Closure $call)
    {
        $this->$method = $call;
    }

    public function __call($method, $args)
    {
        if (isset($this->$method) && $this->$method instanceof Closure) {
            return call_user_func_array($this->$method, $args);
        }
    }
}
```

Will allow you to force call on your "property callable". For example,

```
$c = function($x) {
    return $x*$x;
};

$obj = new Caller();
$obj->bind('foo', $c);
var_dump($obj->foo(4)); //16
```

See sample *[here](http://3v4l.org/udMKa)*.

There may be ways to change the class itself dynamically ([runkit](http://php.net/runkit) and company), but I would strongly recommend to stay away from that as long as possible.

Comment: This is a really great solution, but as you said, it doesn't trick `method_exists`, which is a bummer. The constraints of working with this library means it has to work. I'm pretty sure I'll have to yell at the project owner.

Answer (score 1):

With latest Runkit from http://github.com/zenovich/runkit you can simply write `runkit_method_add(get_class($this), $methodName, $newClosure);`
to do this.